# 1 listview and 3 buttons. 1 button is not clickable, why?

Tags: android, button

I have a class wich extends ListActivity. Inside there are 3 buttons and a listview (clickable items), list items and 2 of the buttons work fine but one doesn't respond to clicks (it is created exactly the same way as the others). I think it is something related with the focusability of the button, i have already tried android:focusable="true" and "false" but nothing changes.

this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp" > 

</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/checkall"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Seleccionar todos"
    android:background="#D1D1D1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/uncheckall"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkall"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Borrar selección"
    android:background="#D1D1D1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

//this is the one not accepting clicks -->
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/mostrar"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Mostrar en mapa"
    android:background="#D1D1D1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add android:clickable="true" android:focusable="false" in all button try this

Comment: and please tell what happens in my case it have worked

Comment: I do not see onClick="..." anywhere. How do you specify what gets called? Do you specify it for the last button?

Comment: are you setting the click listener **for all 3 buttons** or only for 2?

Comment: Abhishek Chaubey- I tried but nothing changes. Yes i set the click listener for all 3, but the button is not even showing the click animation.

Comment: can u show your 3rd button onclickListener

Comment: Oh! yes, the problem was inside the onclicklistener (just a confusing variable name) and the button wasn't showing the click animation because i set a background color, so i thought it wasn't working but it was. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem in your layout and it works fine with this code-behind:

```
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity {

Button checkall, uncheckall, mostrar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    checkall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkall);
    uncheckall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uncheckall);
    mostrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mostrar);

    checkall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "checkall is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    uncheckall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "uncheckall is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    mostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "mostrar is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Try to 'clean' and 'Rebuild' your project or post your code here

Comment: You were right the problem was inside the onclicklistener. Thank you!